# How to create Shim for System.AppDomain class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, microsoft-fakes

In my code I am using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` call.

In my unit test I want to fake this call, so it will always return same value for `BaseDirectory` property.

However, after generating fake assembly for `System` I can't see `ShimAppDomain` in my unit test. Is it becasue `AppDomain` is `sealed class`?

How can I isolate my test from `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` call?

For mocking using [Microsoft Fakes Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175(v=vs.110).aspx) and Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this solution

I. Updated content of `mscorlib.fakes` to

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/" Diagnostic="true">
  <Assembly Name="mscorlib" Version="4.0.0.0"/>
  <StubGeneration>
    <Clear/>
  </StubGeneration>
  <ShimGeneration>
    <Clear/>
    <Add FullName="System.AppDomain"/>
  </ShimGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

II. Added `using System.Fakes` to my Unit Test file

III. Added following to my Unit Test

```
using (ShimsContext.Create())
{
    string baseDir = @"My\Base\Dir";

    ShimAppDomain fakeAppDomain = new ShimAppDomain()
    {
        BaseDirectoryGet = () => { return baseDir; }
    };

    ShimAppDomain.CurrentDomainGet = () => { return fakeAppDomain; };

    string defaultDir = MyConstants.DefaultAppFolder;

    // both baseDir and defaultDir are same "My\Base\Dir"
    Assert.AreEqual(baseDir, defaultDir);
}
```

`Constants.DefaultAppFolder` property is implemented as follows

```
internal static class MyConstants
{
    internal static string DefaultAppFolder
    {
        get
        {
            return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        }
    }
}
```

It is quite verbose, but works.

Comment: And it prooves: * You do not need to break OO and SOLID principles for unit tests, * Most open source mocking libraries are not up to standards, * MS did a quite good job.Yes, it is a little verbose, but it does something really powerfull.